# What is this strange phenomenon?

Tags: riddle

Young, in sinc, think two lines narrow, I'm why a bee won't cast a shadow.

What am I?

Hint:

> I'm not actually Young

Comment: Vanishing point?

Comment: Is "sinc" a typo for "sync", or intentional?

Comment: @aschepler Intentional!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Light diffraction

in sinc

> refers to the mathematical function `sinc(x) = sin(x)/x`, which often comes up in analysis of diffraction patterns

think two lines narrow

> refers to the [Double Slit Experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment), a simple demonstration of diffraction patterns

I'm why a bee won't cast a shadow

> A bee's shadow, unless the bee is rather close to the ground, gets diffracted to the point where you can't see anything.

Comment: Congratulations, well done!

Answer (score 4):

> The phenomenon you are riddling about is the Particle / Wave nature of light

Young

> Thomas Young, famous for the double slit experiment

In sinc

> alluding to the fourier transform of the two box functions that produce the slits. The planar intensity of the light will be a sinc function.

think two lines narrow

> again, two narrow slits used in the experiment

Comment: Good job, only just pipped to the post!